# How to train autoencoder with custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, autoencoder

I'm trying to convert a tutorial that uses the MNIST dataset to train autoencoder to a program that uses local images instead.

In the tutorial, they load and format the data like this: (they also create noisy data from the original.)

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)
```

Then they train it like this:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train,
            epochs=100,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test_noisy, x_test))
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
train
    - original
    - snow

validation
    - original
    - snow
```

This is the way I tried to load the data so far:

```
data_gen_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
data_gen_val = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

x_train = data_gen_train.flow_from_directory(
    directory= path_train,
    target_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    class_mode='input',
)

x_validation = data_gen_val.flow_from_directory(
    directory=path_validation,
    target_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=128,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    class_mode='input',
)
```

Then trained it like this:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train,
            epochs=100,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=x_validation)
```

The problem is the loss of the model keeps increasing with every epoch and the predicted images are all full black. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be nice if you can also post the auto encode model or how it is being loaded to understand this better. Also, if possible post the training curves, loss function and the optimizer you are using